# RedisConnection exists method is always returning null (Spring boot data redis)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have a key visted = "visted", the key is present in the redis db. I am writing program in java. When i am checking with redis template hasKey function it is coming as true.

```
redisTemplate.hasKey(visited)
```

Its coming as true, but when i am doing it in pipeline, using redisConnection exists function it is always coming as null.

```
redisTemplate.executePipelined((RedisCallback<Object>) connection -> {
System.out.println(connection.exists(visted.getBytes()));
return null;
});
```

It is coming as null always. Though i am able to change the value of visited key using the pipeline.

```
redisTemplate.executePipelined((RedisCallback<Object>) connection -> {
connection.set("visited".getBytes(), "false".getBytes());
return null;
});
```

Which sets the value of visited key to "false"

Edit 1:

I also have tried StringRedisConnection to write string value directly through the pipeline.

```
redisTemplate.executePipelined((RedisCallback<Object>) connection -> {
StringRedisConnection stringRedisConnection = (StringRedisConnection)connection;
stringRedisConnection.set("visited", "true");             
System.out.println(stringRedisConnection.exists("visited"));
return null;
));
```

Still i am getting null here.

Answer (score 0):

All operations always return null in RedisTemplate#executePipelined